# mySQL Inclusive search on a flat table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below SQL table, and i'm wondering if it's possible to have an inclusive search with this table format? Meaning if someone were to search for SSNU and ACCOUNT_NO it would only return the data if the CASE ID has an SSNU and ACCOUNT_NO that match the inputs.

[image: table structure]

I've tried a where clause like the below:

```
AND (a.KEY = "ACCOUNT_NO" AND a.VALUE = "XXXXXX")
AND (a.KEY = "GPID" AND a.VALUE = "XXXXX")
```

but have not had any luck.

Comment: Perhaps you should use OR instead of AND.

Comment: OR returns any case when 1 of these shows up. They both need to be present for that caseId.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to prioritize the row whose key is `'ACCOUNT_NO'`, and fallback on `'GPID'`? If you want just one row, then you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select *
from mytable a
where a.key in ('ACCOUNT_NO', 'GPID') and a.value = 'XXXXXX'
order by a.key = 'ACCOUNT_NO' desc
limit 1
```

The `order by` clause puts first the row whose key is `'ACCOUNT_NO'`, if any. Note that I factorized the condition on `VALUE`, since it is common to both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If by "person" you mean "case id", then I think you want aggregation:

```
select case_id
from t
where (a.KEY = 'ACCOUNT_NO' AND a.VALUE = 'XXXXXX') or
      (a.KEY = 'GPID' AND a.VALUE = 'XXXXX')
group by case_id
having count(distinct a.key) = 2;
```

This returns cases that have both the key/value pairs.

Comment: what if one of them could be null? Changing the count etc..

Comment: If one of *what* could be `NULL`.  A null value of `a.key` is not counted using `count(distinct)`.  If you want to count `NULL` values as a separate value, the logic can be tweaked.

Comment: Yes, if one of the *VALUE* were to be NULL not the *KEY*. So while the keys would be distinct, looking for a match of 2 would be thrown off.

Comment: @DaveDennis . . . `NULL` values would not match the conditions unless you use `IS NULL` or a the `NULL`-safe comparison operator `<=>`.